# Java Object <= relational operator check

Tags: java

In Java, when two objects are compared using ==, their references are also compared. But what happens when they are compared using other relational operators? For instance:

```
 Integer a = new Integer(10);
 Integer b = new Integer(9);
 if (a >= b) {
  System.out.println("A is greater");
 }
```

When I run this, I get output as A is greater, why so? Do references not get compared or they do and it's just a coincidence?

Also, if one of the arguments is primitive, does the non-primitive one get unwrapped to primitive for such comparisons?

Comment: Type it into a source file and see what happens with more interesting types.  *In general* it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, the `Integer`(s) are [unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to primitive `int`(s). There is no `<=` (or `>=`) comparison for reference types (without `Comparable`, `Comparator` or similar).

Comment: But if operator overloading is not present, how does it unbox? Is that a compiler optimization?

Comment: Unboxing is a compiler addition that allows Java to convert the wrapper types to the primitive types (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Elliott Frisch 's answer, if the object cannot be unboxed (like instances of `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, `String`, or anything non-numeric), the `compareTo` method of the `Comparable` interface is used, the the result is compared to `0` using relational operators:

```
var a = new BigInteger("10");
var b = new BigInteger("9");
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b) < 0); // prints true, because a < b
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b) > 0); // prints false
```

Comparing non-number objects might be crazy:

```
String x = "abcd";
String y = "defg";
System.out.println(x.compareTo(y) < 0); // prints false, because 'a' < 'd'
```

With this, remember to implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) when you need to compare classes you defined.

Answer (score 0):

Like Elliot Frisch mentioned, the `Integer`s are unboxed to `int`s. Think of this like the object being casted from an Object to a primitive.

Here is the byte code from your Java, which shows that [`Integer.intValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--) is called to get the `int` out of the `Integer`:

```
# Create Integer
NEW java/lang/Integer
DUP
# Store 10 in the Integer
BIPUSH 10
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Integer.<init> (I)V 
ASTORE 1

# Create Integer
NEW java/lang/Integer
DUP
# Store 9 in the Integer
BIPUSH 9
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Integer.<init> (I)V
ASTORE 2

# Get Integer(10)
ALOAD 1
# Call Integer.intValue (returns int 10)
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue ()I
# Get Integer(9)
ALOAD 2
# Call Integer.intValue (returns int 9)
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue ()I 
# Compare 10 < 9
IF_ICMPLT L3
```